# Webpack image paths

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-sass

**Fake edit: I've now made it work by specifying the path from the root src folder rather than the relative path:

`url('/src/assets/example.jpg')`

instead of:

`url('../../assets/example.jpg')`

Is this the norm, or is it down to my webpack config and lack of knowledge? I'm sure I'll find out shortly, but I hope this will also work with webpack-dev-server

---

Original question:

I'm struggling to resolve image urls from my sass files.

My output is in a folder called dist, and I can navigate to my images at localhost:port/dist/images (so I think I'm including them correctly in app.js)

Basic question I know, but I'm not sure why a relative path to the image isn't working.

File structure:

```
dist
|--> images
   | example.jpg
|--> js
   | bundle.js
| index.html
```

From this src folder:

```
src
|--> assets
   | example.jpg
|--> js
   | app.js
|--> sass
   | ... sass folders
   | main.scss
| index.ejs
| .babelrc
| browserlistrc
| package.json
| webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'js/bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // JS
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /\node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            // SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
            },
            // ASSESTS
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash:5].[ext]',
                        outputPath: './images/'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './src/index.ejs'        
        })
    ]
};
```

Thanks